# OrientDB console diagnostic - not very helpful?

Tags: orientdb

I am running some OrientDB script and getting the below. How can I make it report lines in the script with the error - the error message is super unhelpful?

Also, `doing SET VERBOSE 10;` at the beginning does not help either.

```
...
Property created successfully.

Property created successfully.

Property created successfully.

Property created successfully.

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class not found: Subscription
    DB name="my.db"

Loading script /Users/hristostoyanov/projects/gitlab/peruncs/recres_repos/recres/recres-webapp/src/main/odb/scripts/sample_data.sql...
Disconnecting from the database [my.db]...OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be Orient DB 3.0.2 [issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/8331)

Also, if you need better feedback during long script execution, start the script with:

```
set echo on;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class not found: Subscription
    DB name="my.db"
```

means that you're trying to execute a command on a Class that doesn't exists, in this case Subscription.

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I know what it means, but I would appreciate a line number where this reference occurs